# Access system icons with NodeJS

Tags: linux, node.js

I'm developing a HTML5 app with [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit).

I want my application to follow the icon theme of the host computer that runs it (primarly Linux hosts).

Frameworks such as `GTK+` or `QT` successfully find the corresponding icon of a standard stock (such as NEW_FILE) based on the user's theme.

GTK icons theme are installed at **$HOME/.icons** or **/usr/share/icons** and icons theme share a common directory structure.

But is it any rule or algorithm to get an exact icon?

How can I look up a (**NEW_FILE**, **SAVE_FILE** or whatever) stock icon within the users theme?

I'm quite lost with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could look in the source code for GTK+ or QT and see how they determine the right icons?